# Use public class from Activity in xml with attrbs (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-xml

I have created a public class in my `main activity` e.g.:

```
public class ActivityMain extends FragmentActivity {
     // ...

    public class MyClass extends Something implements SomethingListener{

        public MyClass(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        // Listener overrides

    }    
}
```

And I use it in my layout xml like:

```
<my.package.ActivityMain.MyClass
   app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
   //parameters
/>
```

That way I get a `ClassNotFoundException` just on the `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)` line in Activity's `onCreate()`.

Also the xml design editor on Android Studio complains about this class:

```
Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
my.package.ActivityMain$MyClass.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)
```

---

If I used in the xml the class which I extend, all render good. E.g:

xml:

```
<external.package.Something
   android:id="@+id/object"
   app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
   //parameters
/>
```

ActivityMain:

```
Something something = (Something) findViewById(R.id.object)
something.setSomethingListener(new SomethingListener( ... ))
```

---

Of course the above solves this issue but **is it possible to use a class created in an Activity in my XML?**

---

**Update:**

The `Something` class has custom attributes e.g. `app:pstsShouldExpand="true"` not sure if they are passed down to it from my `MyClass`. It might be the issue.

Comment: does youur `Something` class `extends View` ?

Comment: @MAC Yes. In fact `Something` is `PagerSlidingTabStrip` which extends `HorizontalScrollView` > `FrameLayout` > `ViewGroup` > `View`